I am looking for a movie where a teenage boy can predict when a tragedy will happen.
A few years ago I watched a movie where the main character was a white teenage boy who was able to predict when a tragedy would happen. 
There was a scene where another white Male teenager was having sex inside a tent near a pool with a black teenage girl. The girl wanted to stop at some point and then the boy told her to keep going. When they were done he went to swim in the pool, and got sucked in to a hole in the pool. 
I believe he was taken to the hospital after that. Where the main character visited him, but when he walked in the the room something fell through the room and crushed the boy he was visiting. 
The last scene I remember was at the end of the movie. Where the main character was sitting in a restauraunt with a couple of female friends, and he was in crutches and had a few cast on him. He sat there knowing that he would die at that moment because of a bus that crashed through the restaurant and killed him. 

Is it a final destination movie? xD

It's Final Destination ,(alternatively known as Final Destination 4) is a 2009 American 3D supernatural horror film written by Eric Bress and directed by David R. Ellis.
Here the boy is not predicting the accidents, he gets to see the future accident and when he saves his friends who supposed to die in that accident, later die one by one.
From wiki

College student Nick O'Bannon attends a race at the McKinley Speedway with his girlfriend Lori Milligan and their friends Hunt Wynorski and Janet Cunningham. Nick suddenly has a premonition of a terrible accident that sends debris into the stadium, killing several people and causing the stadium to collapse.

One of his friend died in the pool as you said.

After receiving a premonition involving water, Nick tries to warn Hunt, who has gone for one last conquest at the pool, while George and Lori try to find Janet, who becomes immobilized in a malfunctioning car wash. Hunt drops his lucky coin in the water after an accidental placement of a toy turned the pool's drain on. As he dives into the pool, he is pulled down to the drain where the pressure mounts, and his insides are eventually ripped into the draining system before Nick can rescue him. 

But he is not the one taken to hospital.

Four days later, Nick then remembers a cowboy, Jonathan Groves, they had jeered at during the race who had changed seats prior to the premonition coming true. Nick and George track Jonathan down at a hospital, where he remained in traction recovering from the stadium's debris. After a bathtub left on in the floor above causes Johnathan's electric equipment to start sparking, falling from his bed and trying to cross the room, Nick and George witness him being crushed as the tub crashes through the weakened floor. 

And at the end when the boy and his other two friends sitting in a coffee shop they get hit by a truck.

Just as he realizes this and sees another omen, the scaffolding outside collapses causing a truck to swerve and crash into the coffee shop. As the scene switches to x-ray Janet is crushed under the truck's tires, Lori is internally decapitated by the impact, and Nick is propelled into a wall and killed.


Note that the film title is officially The Final Destination. Presumably the production company figured (wrongly) that this would be the final movie of the series, whereas in fact there is a sequel to this movie: Final Destination 5.
